# The code where I use StringBuilder (example:builder.append,builder.replace) giving me a compile error. Everything else is ok

Tags: java, stringbuilder

I am trying to write a sudoku "solver" and netbeans is giving me 3 error messages relating to StringBuilder. I had different files for each class but it wouldn't compile then either. Every site i have visited has suggested the way I am doing it. Please help.

```
public class Sudoku {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] mainpuzzle =
             {{5, 3, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0},
              {6, 0, 0, 1, 9, 5, 0, 0, 0},
              {0, 9, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0},
              {8, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 3},
              {4, 0, 0, 8, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1},
              {7, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 6},
              {0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 8, 0},
              {0, 0, 0, 4, 1, 9, 0, 0, 5},
              {0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 7, 9}};        
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();  
        for (int i = 0; i < 81; i++) {
            builder.append("09123456789");        // 11 
        }
        for (int j = 0;j < 9; j++ ) {
            for ( int k = 0;k < 9;k++ ) {
               if ( mainpuzzle [j][k] != 0 ) {
                 String replace1 = String.valueOf(mainpuzzle[j][k]); 
                 builder.replace((j*11) + (k*11), (j*11) + (k*11), 
                                                        replace1);
               }
            }
        }
        GetSquareCandidates getSqCandid = new GetSquareCandidates();
        StringBuilder builderMarkup = new StringBuilder();
        builderMarkup = getSqCandid(builder);

     }
}  

class GetSquareCandidates {
   public StringBuilder GetSquareCandidates(StringBuilder boxPassed) 
       StringBuilder boxRet = new StringBuilder();
       boxRet = boxPassed;

       return boxRet;
    }

}
```

Comment: And the errors are?

Comment: We need to see the compiler errors in order to help you solve them. Also, the errors should indicate which line has the problem. Please indicate that in your source code.

Comment: I suspect you're not doing what you think you're doing here: `builder.replace((j*11) + (k*11), (j*11) + (k*11), replace1);`

Comment: I was wondering about the math of that line.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, there are a couple of things missing like below

1. `GetSquareCandidates` class's `GetSquareCandidates` method does not have an open curly brace.
2. `getSqCandid(StringBuilder builder)` method not defined in your `GetSquareCandidates` class.

Other than these, please share compilation error messages.

Comment: Netbeans has underlined append and replace for builder as well as getSqCandid(builder).

Comment: It says "cannot find symbol".

Answer (score 0):

There are only a few errors please find below:

- **Case 1.** If `public StringBuilder GetSquareCandidates(StringBuilder boxPassed)` is a `constructor` then it can't `return`.
- **Case 2.** If it is method then kindly do below changes:

  - Call the method using `builderMarkup = getSqCandid.GetSquareCandidates(builder);`
  - Add `{` after `public StringBuilder GetSquareCandidates(StringBuilder boxPassed)`.

It is recommended using method name like `getSquareCandidates()`.